# How to reinterpret IO signal when testing chisel3 modules

Tags: chisel

I have a chisel3 module with a data bus IO that can be reinterpreted to some instruction/command
using bundle, aka(in the module):

```scala
......
 //io.data is for example UInt(64.W)
 val cmdInterface = new CommandInterface() // this is a bundle of signals
 val cmd = io.data.asTypeof(cmdInterface)
......
```

I can do the reinterpretation inside Module definition but this is not possible inside the PeekPokeTester:

```scala
//using the tester:
poke(c.io.data.asTypeof(cmdInterface).cmd, 1) // this is not ok
```

the compiling gives:
`chisel3.internal.ChiselException: Error: Not in a UserModule. Likely cause: Missed Module() wrap, bare chisel API call, or attempting to construct hardware inside a BlackBox.`
at the line of the asTypeOf(xxxx)

So, how to reinterpret IO signals when testing?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer, but [chisel-testers2](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-testers2) is designed to resolve this difficulty. Here is an example from its unit tests [BundleLiteralsSpec](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-testers2/blob/master/src/test/scala/chisel3/tests/BundleLiteralsSpec.scala)

```
  it should "roundtrip Bundle literals" in {
    test(new PassthroughModule(new DoubleElements)) { c =>
      c.in.poke(chiselTypeOf(c.in).Lit(_.a -> 0.U, _.b -> 1.U))
      c.in.poke(c.out.peek())
      c.out.expect(chiselTypeOf(c.in).Lit(_.a -> 0.U, _.b -> 1.U))
    }
  }
```

In this example it is getting the BundleType from the input itself but could as easily be re-written with direct BundleReferences e.g.

```
c.in.poke((new DoubleElements).Lit(_.a -> 0.U, _.b -> 1.U))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val cmdInterface = Module(new CommandInterface()) // this is a bundle of signals
```

Try this instead. It should work.

Comment: I don't think this will work, the CommandInterface is a bundle, aka,defined as class CommandInterface extends Bundle{...}